# Angular 2 Component repeater based upon items in data model array

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-template

A simple datamodel:

```
export class Artboard {
    private layers: Array<Layer> = new Array<Layer>();

    constructor(layersParam: Layer[] = null) {
        this.layers = layersParam;
    }
}
```

Gets passed into a corresponding component:

```
<app-ipe-container>
    <app-ipe-artboard [artboard]="artboard"></app-ipe-artboard>
</app-ipe-container>

@Component({
    selector: 'app-ipe-artboard'
})
export class ArtboardComponent {
    @Input() public artboard: Artboard;
}
```

So far so good. Now in this artboard.component the array of layers (which is populated) is repeated to create layer.component (and also pass through the layer object).

```
<app-ipe-artboard-layer *ngFor="let layer of artboard.layers" [layer]="layer"></app-ipe-artboard-layer>
```

"Unfortunately" this doesn't work (yet). The browser's inspector reveals this:

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
```

...instead of having multiple `<app-ipe-artboard-layer>` components / tags.

How to implement this logic?

Comment: please define "doesn't work"

Comment: this looks like this entire block <app-ipe-artboard-layer *ngFor="let layer of artboard.layers" [layer]="layer"></app-ipe-artboard-layer> is not rendered because of some *ngIf or something. can you provide more code?

Comment: Your comment pointed me to have a look in the layer.component.html...there was an invalid binding in there that kept the component from rendering. Thanks for your help! So actually the setup works just fine :) What to do with this question? Close it?

Comment: I can post the comment as the answer and you can mark it as checked, would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This html comment renders in Angular when part of the template is not rendered because it is wrapped in an *ngIf block or *ngSwitchcase. It looks like this entire block  is not rendered.